# Convert Base64 String to String Array

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets

I am using request.getParameter and getting this value:

```
[
  "data:image/jpeg;base64,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",
  "data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
]
```

How do I convert it to array?

When I use `request.getParameterValues("jsondata");` I get this value  `[Ljava.lang.String;@8892fd8`, which is not expected.

Comment: See [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/409784/5221149) for why you're printing `[Ljava.lang.String;@8892fd8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jsondata` value is JSON text. It starts with `[`, which means it's a JSON array.

To process it, you should use a JSON parser. See [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2591098/5221149).

Once you have parsed it, you should have a `String[]` or a `List<String>`, with 2 values.

Both values start with `data:image/jpeg;base64,` followed by Base-64 encoded binary data (JPEG image).

Assuming you have Java 8 or later, use the [`Base64`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) class to decode into a `byte[]`.

You now have your 2 JPEG images, in the form of 2 byte arrays.